# Grafana - How can we join data from TimescaleDB and ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, timescaledb

Populate data from TimescaleDB and ElasticSearch based on a field which is present in both data sources.

Comment: Could you give more details about what exactly you need?

Comment: I want to join TimeScaleDB data source and ElasticSearch data source and fetch the record, based on a particular match and visualize the data into Grafana.                         Time Scale DB Data:

Comment: Time Scale DB  Data:
Id: 1
Device_id: 2323

Id : 2
Device_id : 2324



Elastic Search Data:
Device_id: 2323
Device_id: 2312

Result:
Id: 1
Device_id: 2323

Comment: I think you can try ZomboDB https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [Transformations feature](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transformations/) of Grafana is exactly what you are looking for.

- Once you have both datasources set up, you can create a panel and select the "Mixed" datasource.
- Write two queries for this same panel, but make sure that the common column is returned with the exact same name in both.
- Then go to the *Transform* tab (next to *Query*, below the panel in editor mode).
- Try to add either

  - a *Merge* transformation (last in the list), this should automatically pick up the common columns (make sure you have only one common column).
  - or an *Outer join* transformation, where you have to manually select the column to join by.